# Binning data based on one column in 2D array and estimate mean in each bin using cython

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, cython

In order to optimize the speed of my code which is very vital for the speed of my MCMC, I want to substitute some of the bottlenecks of my python code with cython. Since I am working with a huge two dimensional array and I need to bin the data based on one column of the 2D array and then find the mean in each bin in all other columns based on binning in the first column, I used to use this python code:

```
   import numpy as np
   d = np.random.random((10**5, 3))
  #binning data again based on first column 
   bins = np.linspace(ndata[0,0], ndata[-1,0], 10)
   #compute the mean in each bin for different input parameters
   digitized = np.digitize(ndata[:,0], bins)
   r= np.array([ndata[digitized == i,0].mean() for i in range(1, len(bins))])
   p= np.array([ndata[digitized == i,1].mean() for i in range(1, len(bins))])
   q= np.array([ndata[digitized == i,2].mean() for i in range(1, len(bins))])
```

How could I speed up at least two order of magnitude with `cython` code by using another code instead of `numpy.digitize`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you need cython for this, I think you're looking for `numpy.bincount`. Here is an example:

```
import numpy as np
d = np.random.random(10**5)
numbins = 10

bins = np.linspace(d.min(), d.max(), numbins+1)
# This line is not necessary, but without it the smallest bin only has 1 value.
bins = bins[1:]
digitized = bins.searchsorted(d)

bin_means = (np.bincount(digitized, weights=d, minlength=numbins) /
             np.bincount(digitized, minlength=numbins))
```

#### Update

Lets take a second to discuss why the above code is faster than the code in your question and why cython will (probably) not help much in this case. In your code when you do `[digitized == i] for i in range(numbins)]`, you're doing `numbins` passes over the `digitized` array. If you're familiar with [big O notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), that's O(n * m). On the other hand bincount does something a little different. Bincount is equivelent, more or less, to:

```
def bincount(digitized, Weights):
   out = zeros(digitized.max() + 1)
   for i, w = zip(digitized, Weights):
       out[i] += w
   return out
```

It has 1 pass (well 2 passes if you count the max) over `digitized` so it has complexity O(n). Also bincount is already written in C and compiled so it already has very little overhead and is very fast. Cython is most helpful when you have code which has a lot of interpreter and type-check overhead so that declaring types and compiling the code removes that overhead. Hope that's helpful.

Comment: Do you think it is more efficient and takes less time to be done compare to my approach?

Comment: It's much, much faster, but I wouldn't take my word for it. Build a test and profile it.

Comment: Nice explanation. With only 10 bins, it is possible that `np.digitize` will be faster than `np.searchsorted`. The former does a linear search, the latter a binary search.

Comment: @Jaime that's really an implementation detail, is there any reason that digitize could not be (and I would argue should be) implemented as a binary search? I see no reason that a well implemented binary search should not always be faster than a linear search.

Comment: @BiRico I wrote two small code and cProfile them. Well, my first solution took `0.683 seconds` while your answer `0.140 seconds`, surely an improvement but I need it would take less. Is there anyway to decrease the time to 0.1 or 0.01 order of mine?

Comment: @Dalek, it really depends on where the bottle neck is. When I'm trying to optimize code, I write the code so that each line contains the smallest possible unit of code and then run it with a [line profiler](https://pythonhosted.org/line_profiler/). Without more specifics about what you're working on and more timing info I'm not sure I can much more use.

Comment: An unsuccessful comparison in a linear search requires a single addition to a pointer address to be ready for the next comparison. In a binary search, you have to first compute the new index (typically done as a subtraction, a right shift and an addition), and then get a pointer to that address (which will involve a multiplication of the index by the stride plus an addition). So it isn't unreasonable to expect a binary search step to be 4-5 times slower than a linear search step.

Comment: Of course a linear search will on average take N/2 steps, while binary searches take log2 N steps. If I did the math right, the break even point for this very simplified analysis is around 10 items. Anything less than that, you are going to be better off with a linear search. It's similar to how fast sorting algorithms like quicksort usually resort to a quadratic time algorithm like selection sort when the problem has been reduced to sorting a sequence of less than ~20 items.

Comment: @Jaime Thanks for the information but I still curious to know whether how much specifying the type, like what we do in cython and c might reduce the speed of operation?

Comment: @BiRico well the answer was not quite what I expected as I already mentioned in the title but your answer was very comprehensive and quite helpful!